# Consistency strength of some problems about singular cardinals

Tags: set-theory, forcing

What is the consistency strength of singularizing a regular cardinal with forcing? Is it exactly a measurable cardinal? Of course the consistency strength of "$V\subseteq W$, $\kappa$ regular in $V$ and singular in $W$" is just zero sharp, but what if we only look at (set) forcing extensions, or perhaps pairs of models that are in some sense close?

Not sure if related: what is the consistency strength of adding (with forcing) an unbounded subset to a *singular* cardinal without adding any bounded subsets?

Probably unrelated: is it possible to add unbounded subset to $\aleph_\omega$ without adding bounded subset? Do large cardinals imply the existence (not just consistency) of such a forcing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the exact strength of singularizing a regular cardinal by forcing is a measurable cardinal. This is due to Dodd-Jensen. The point is that if there is no inner model with a measurable cardinal and $\lambda$ is a singular cardinal in a forcing extension $V[G]$, then by the covering theorem below a measurable, $\lambda$ is singular in the core model of $V[G]$. But the core model of $V[G]$ is equal to the core model of $V$, and so $\lambda$ is singular in $V$.

Similarly, the strength of adding an unbounded subset to a singular cardinal without adding bounded subsets (by any means, not just set forcing) is one measurable cardinal. This is because if $M\subseteq N$ are models with the same ordinals and $M$ has the Jensen covering property in $N$, then if $M$ and $N$ have the same bounded subsets of a singular cardinal $\lambda$, then $P(\lambda)\cap M = P(\lambda) \cap N$. This is similar to the proof under the assumption that $0^\#$ does not exist, which appears in the "Large cardinals and $L$" chapter of Jech's textbook.

Finally, I do think large cardinals imply a forcing that adds a subset to $\aleph_\omega$ but no bounded subsets, at least if $\aleph_{\omega}$ is a strong limit cardinal. If $\delta$ is Woodin, and $G\subseteq \mathbb Q^{\aleph_\omega}_{{<}\delta}$ is $V$-generic for the size $\aleph_\omega$ stationary tower, then letting $j_G : V\to M$ be the generic embedding, $M^{\aleph_\omega}\cap V[G]\subseteq M$, and $\text{crit}(j_G) = \aleph_{\omega+1}^V$, so at least assuming $\aleph_{\omega}$ is a strong limit, $P(\aleph_n)^V = P(\aleph_n)^M = P(\aleph_n)^{V[G]}$. More information about the size $\kappa$ stationary tower appears in Larson's "Six lectures on the stationary tower."

Comment: A possibly silly question: say that a cardinal $\lambda$ is **singularizable** iff there is some inner model $M$ in which $\lambda$ is regular but which has a set forcing extension in which $\lambda$ is singular. Must there be an inner model in which $\lambda$ itself is measurable?

Comment: Yes. By the above answer, $M$ has an inner model with a measurable cardinal. If zero dagger does not exist in $M$, then by the specifics of the covering lemma for $L[U]$, $\lambda$ must be the measurable cardinal of $L[U]$ (and there is a Prikry generic through $U$ in $M[G]$). Otherwise, zero dagger exists in $M$, which implies that every uncountable cardinal of $M$ is measurable in an inner model, since we can iterate an $L[U]$ model where $U$ lies on a countable ordinal of $M$.

Comment: Great, thanks - I'm not too comfortable with the details of the covering lemmas so I wanted to check.

Comment: Just to make sure--how to add unbounded subset to singular with just a measurable? Can we consider $V\subseteq V[H]\subseteq V[G]$ where $V\subseteq V[G]$ is Prikry extension and $H$ is the even coordinates of the Prikry generic sequence $G$?

Comment: Yes, that works. I think a modification of this idea can even add a subset to $\aleph_\omega$ without adding bounded subsets.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg See my paper [Two remarks on Merimovich's model of the total failure of GCH](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.00748)

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Good to hear from you. I was actually wondering if you knew how to prove it is consistent that one can add a new $\omega$-sequence to $\aleph_\omega$ starting with just a measurable. I thought a little bit and wasn't able to get my idea to work. But you mentioned this here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201555/can-the-first-ordinal-in-which-v-neq-hod-be-aleph-omega

Comment: Yes, I think just a measurable is sufficient. The idea should be like this: start with $\kappa$ measurable and force with Gitik-Magidor extender based forcing to make $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$ and add just $\kappa^+$-many Prikry sequences call this model $V_2$. For intermediate model $V_1$ just consider the forcing which adds the Prikry sequence related to the normal measure one and the collapses. Now one can mange $V_1 \subset V_2$ and there are many new Prikry sequences in $V_2$ but not in $V_1$. Furthermore the two models have the same bounded subsets of $\kappa.$

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Great, thank you!